# 'the pipe is being closed' error using Geolocator in Windows 8 Metro Javascript application

Tags: javascript, geolocation, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Using the following code, I am receiving the following errors:

```
the pipe is being closed
```

and

```
the wait operation timed out
```

Code:

```
var loc = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
loc.getGeopositionAsync().done(function (pos) {
    console.log(pos);
});
```

I am running this within the Windows 8 simulator, and have attempted both with the Simulated location enabled and disabled.

What is causing this error, and what is the correct manner in which to use the Geolocator to successfully retrieve the users location both on a real GPS enabled device, and in the simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, both on my local machine and in the simulator, on Windows 8 Release Preview.

I tested it in the simulator both with the simulated location on and off.

One thing to check...do you have Location enabled in the Capabilities section of your app manifest?

Also, you may want to try writing the location info to the screen...the code above will simply pass the pos object to the console, so you wouldn't actually know if it was returning correct geolocation information even if you get past the error.

Here's what I did:

1. Start with a new Blank JavaScript app.
2. open default.html, and add an id of "geo" to the `<p>` tag containing the default content.
3. Add the following code to the app.onactivated handler to test (I added my code just before the closing brace:

   ```
   var loc = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geolocator();
   loc.getGeopositionAsync().done(function (pos) {
       console.log(pos);
       var geo = document.getElementById("geo");
       geo.innerText = pos.coordinate.latitude + ", " + pos.coordinate.longitude;
   });
   ```

The machine I'm testing on is a laptop with no GPS, so the underlying API will use WiFi or IP address info for the geolocation. If GPS is available, it should be used for the location data transparently to your app.

Comment: Yeah, this errors the same as my example. My app does have the location capabilities enabled.

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? And have you tried using the W3C geolocation syntax? While I haven't tried it since the developer preview, I was able to successfully port some code I'd written using the W3C syntax at that time.

Comment: `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure);`
  
`function success(position) {`
`    console.log('You are at: ' + position.coords.latitude + ', ' + position.coords.longitude + '!');`
`}`

Comment: I'm still receiving the same error. Thanks for the suggestions. I have contacted a colleague at Microsoft suggesting that its a bug, albeit intermittent (as you folks don't seem to have an issue with it).

Comment: Are you seeing the issue consistently? Do you have the ability to test it on another machine?

Comment: I am seeing it consistently, unfortunately I don't have another machine to test this on. I might look at creating a virtual machine to do an isolated test.